# how to modify axis labels ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I know there are other questions like this. However, this is a bit of two fold item.

So, i am using the following code to arrange my horizontal bar chart in descending order by annual difference, A. First is the sample data and then making the data frame.

```
  A<- c(150,125,0,-300,-350,-370)
  Series<- c("Construction","Manufacturing","Information","Health_Care","Education","Government")

  testdf <- data.frame(A,Series)

  jobgrowth<-ggplot(data=testdf,mapping=aes(x=A,y=Series))+ 
  geom_col(color="blue")+aes(x = reorder(Series,A),A)+ coord_flip()
```

The issue is that my y-axis label is showing as "reorder(Series,A)". I added the second aes segment as an attempt to have them arranged by descending order (greatest number at the top). PPrior to that, it was arranging them in a random (as far as i can tell) order. How do I get the y-axis label to show nothing? Second, If I wanted the title to be directly above the chart, what is the method for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to call `aes` twice, you can `reorder` in the call to `ggplot`. From there you can use `labs` with `x = NULL` to get rid of the x-axis lable and `ggtitle` to add a title. You can call `theme` to move the title to the exact center. If you prefer it centered over the plot area, remove the `plot.title.position` line.

```
ggplot(data=testdf, aes(y=A, x = reorder(Series,A))) + 
      geom_col(color="blue") + coord_flip() +
  labs(x = NULL) + ggtitle("Interesting Title") +
  theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]