# Non-numeric argument error to binary operation in R, needs explanation

Tags: r, ggplot2, syntax-error, numeric

This is a continuation of ([how to modify axis labels ggplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569149/how-to-modify-axis-labels-ggplot-in-r)). The code supplied works beautifully. The data is created manually. So I transferred that a larger dataset and am now getting the following error.

```
   Error in aes(y = AnnualDifference, x = (reorder(Seriesttls, AnnualDifference))) +  :
   non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

This is the code being used

```
   jobgrowthbyindustry<-ggplot(data=nvces2, aes(y=AnnualDifference,x= 
   (reorder(Seriesttls,AnnualDifference)))+geom_col(color="blue")
   +coord_flip()+labs(x=NULL)+ggtitle("Nevada Nonfarm Job Growth by Industry"))+
   theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
   plot.title = element_text(hjust =0.5))
```

If this is of any assistance, the AnnualDifference item is created using the following code

```
  nvces<- nvces%>%
  group_by(adjusted,areaname,seriescode)%>%
  mutate(PreviousYear=lag(ravg,12), 
     PreviousMonth=lag(ravg),
     AnnualDifference=ravg-PreviousYear,
     MonthlyDifference=ravg-PreviousMonth,
     MonthlyGrowthRate=MonthlyDifference/PreviousMonth,
     PercentGrowthRate=AnnualDifference/PreviousYear)%>%
  ungroup()
```

Where my confusion comes is that the data types for the items involved in the chart are the same. Seriesttls is character and AnnualDifference (or A in the previous question) is numeric. Yet in the first I get no errors and in the second one, I do. Any thoughts on why this is?

Comment: Can head provide some data that replicates your error? I assume you check `class` of each column and not assumed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, this error typically pops up if I got one of the parentheses wrong and am trying to add something within the call to `ggplot`. Your formatting makes this difficult to see, so let's look at this more nicely formatted:

```
   jobgrowthbyindustry <- 
      ggplot(data=nvces2, 
             aes(y = AnnualDifference, 
                 x = (reorder(Seriesttls,AnnualDifference))   
                 )
             + geom_col(color="blue")
             + coord_flip()
             + labs(x=NULL)
             + ggtitle("Nevada Nonfarm Job Growth by Industry")
             ) + theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
                       plot.title = element_text(hjust =0.5)
             )
```

One of the parentheses is misplaced.

It should be:

```
   jobgrowthbyindustry <- 
      ggplot(data=nvces2, 
             aes(y = AnnualDifference, 
                 x = (reorder(Seriesttls,AnnualDifference))   
                 )
             ) +
     geom_col(color="blue") +
     coord_flip() +
     labs(x=NULL) +
     ggtitle("Nevada Nonfarm Job Growth by Industry") +
     theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
           plot.title = element_text(hjust =0.5)
           )
```

And you can also remove the redundant `()` around the call to `reorder`.

If this is not resolving your issue, please do provide some data so that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: This had not entered my mental list of possibilities because there was no red x or error on the left side of R studio. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: yeah, the error here isn't particularly helpful. I have made this mistakes so often that it became the first thing fo me to look for.